# How to use multiple Clappr in slider, vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js, clappr

I have created a slider consisting of multiple images and videos. I use Swiper and Clappr (video player), but clappr doesn't work with multiple videos.

I tried to fix it through a cycle (code below), but even so, the script only works for the first video.

Vue v.3.1, Clappr v.0.3, Swiper v.4.5.

```
<section class="content__slider swiper-container"
         v-if="project_data && project_data.length">

    <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
        <li v-for="(object, index) in project_data" :key="index"
            class="content-item swiper-slide">

            <!-- it'll be show, if obj type is images -->
            <v-lazy-image v-if="object.type === 'images'"
                          :src="object.data"
                          class="content-img"/>

            <!-- it'll be show, if obj type is video -->
            <div v-if="object.type === 'video'"
                 class="content-video"
                 :id="'container_' + index"></div>

        </li>
    </ul>

</section>
```

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Swiper from "swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm.bundle";
import VLazyImage from "v-lazy-image";
import Clappr from 'clappr'

import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css'

export default {
    name: "Project",
    data: () => ({
        project_data: [], // data of project
        project_images: [], // arr of images
        project_videos: [], // arr of videos
    }),
    created() {

        axios.get('/getWorks/' + this.$route.params.name)
            .then(response => {

                 let arr = [];

                 this.project_images = response.data.work_images;
                 let images = response.data.work_images;

                 this.project_videos = response.data.work_videos;
                 let videos = response.data.work_videos;

                 for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                     arr.push({"type": "images", "data": "/storage/" + images[i]});
                 }
                 for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
                     arr.push({"type": "video", "data": "/storage/" + videos[i]});
                 }

                 this.project_data = arr;

            })
            .then(() => {

                // init slider
                new Swiper('.content__slider', {
                    mousewheel: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    speed: 1200,
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: '.content-arrow.swiper-button-next',
                        prevEl: '.content-arrow.swiper-button-prev',
                    },
                    pagination: {
                        el: '.content-pagination.swiper-pagination',
                        type: 'fraction',
                    },
                    breakpoints: {
                        959: {
                            zoom: {
                                maxRatio: 5,
                                toggle: true,
                                containerClass: '.content__slider',
                                zoomedSlideClass: '.content-item'
                            },
                        }
                    }
                });

                // init clappr (video player)
                if ( document.querySelector('.content-video') ) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.project_videos.length; i++) {
                        new Clappr.Player({
                            source: '/storage/' + this.project_videos[i],
                            parentId: '#container_' + (this.project_images.length - i),
                            mute: true,
                            width: document.querySelector('.content-item').offsetWidth,
                            height: document.querySelector('.content-item').offsetHeight
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

It's works for the first video in array, but not for the following

Answer (score 0):

Live and learn, I did not notice my mistake.

```
parentId: '#container_' + (this.project_images.length + i)
```

It was necessary to summarize. Now, it works)

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is:**

1. you are initializing clappr on created hook (not ideal)
2. you are initializing only the first one due to using `v-if

The created hook is triggered before the component is finished building its DOM, therefore in theory, you would not be able to find any elements via your `document.querySelector`.

**Why does this work tho?**

Since you are running this querySelector inside a asynchronous function(the ajax call from axios), this means that the time it takes the server to respond your call to `/getWorks/`, the browser has been done creating the DOM. This is pure luck and not what you would want to do.

**Solution to #1;** Change created hook to a mounted hook. – Mounted is the hook Vue uses to tell you that the DOM is build and completed.

The second issue is that you are using v-if to "hide" the other elements. v-if completly removes the element from DOM. This makes your querySelector not being able to find it and initialize it. (Because there is only one, and that is your first  element:

> so, the script only works for the first video.

**Solution to #2** Change `v-if` to `v-show` – v-show is keeping the element in DOM but hiding it via CSS. Therefore it is accessible via querySelector.